# Open TIFF data in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcmap

[image][image]

I can't open this TIFF data in GIS (can´t see the Attribute Table or convert them to polygon)

https://gitlab.com/hotmaps/vol_res_curr_density/blob/master/data/vol_res_curr_density.tif

Comment: And how can i convert them into polygon?

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to do? Tiff file seems to be OK, it is 1-band image with pixel having 32 bit floating point values. Data fall mostly to the low end (500-12500).

Comment: @user30184 I want to calculate the space heating of dwellings in 100x100m

Comment: Picture No.1 is the tif-data in arcgis and Picture No.2 is the same data convert into polygon which show the Values in graduated colors

Answer (score 2):

You can’t view an attribute table or convert to polygons if your data is not integer format. You have a few options. If you really want to convert to polygons or view the Raster table, multiply your raster by some constant (I.e. 100), then convert to integer; 2 decimal places would be maintained in my example. You could also use the “Raster to Point” tool to create a vector point at the centre of each raster cell instead.

But more likely to be appropriate would be the “Zonal Statistics” (to quantify raster cells within features of a dwelling polygon layer) or “Block Statistics” tools (quantify raster values within non-overlapping blocks of a defined window size).  These tools require the Spatial Analyst extension.